# Object in Params Android

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am getting user information in an object i.e. student and sending it to server in Android using volley. Currently, I am sending data like this:

```
private Map<String, String> params;
public SignUpVolleyReq(Student student, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Email", student.getEmail());
    params.put("Password", student.getPassword());
    params.put("Name", student.getName());
    params.put("Location", student.getLocation());
    params.put("phone", student.getPhone());
    params.put("Interests", student.getInterests());
    params.put("Skills", student.getSkills());

    params.put("Institute", student.getInstitute());
    params.put("Program", student.getProgram());
    params.put("gradYear", student.getGradYear() + "");
    params.put("Marks", student.getMarks() + "");
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

Is this the right way? or Instead of sending the fields separately, Can I send the whole student object? I have a PHP script on server which receives data and save it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send a Java object to a PHP script, it's quite obvious lol. I think this is a good method. Another way can be encoding the Java object in a string, passing the encoded string in only one HTTP param. and then php will decode that string and maybe store it in an assoc array or an object.

The encoded string may be easier to handle on both the sides but it may be useless additional computations for both Android and PHP.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to know that is this a good approach or not and you answered it.